# regarding salesforce knowledge

Tags: force.com-sites

http://capitalonespark.force.com/sparkbusinessfaq/articles/Spark_Business_FAQ/Bank-Accounts-Deposits/?l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1 this is the url of my company 
whereas in the mobile http://capitalonespark.force.com/sparkbusinessfaq/pkb_mobile#/articles/Spark_Business_FAQ/Bank-Accounts-Deposits/
It is showing different page layouts can somebody verify this issue? 
 IN the web we are able to see the article types but in mobile you are not seeing?

Comment: Verified........

Comment: Seems you are using this appexchange product to expose your knowledge articles:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU

It also appears you've enabled the mobile site in the PKB settings but have not modified/replaced the standard mobile template. Off the top of my head I think the Visualforce page is pkb_mobile.

Comment: Thanks. what do you mean standard mobile template means?and we have 3 different templates for this Pkb